# Is it possible to add performance monitor metrics to AppInsights with an ASP .NET Core app?

Tags: asp.net-core, performancecounter, azure-application-insights

We are running an ASP .NET core app and have it configured to send telemetry to AppInsights. I'd also like to collect perf mon counters on the servers supporting the app in AppInsights, like memory and CPU usage. Is this possible? I have perf mon counters configured with our standard .NET apps in AppInsights, but can't see how to configure it with .NET Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ASP.NET Core app is compiled under full framework NET 4.5.1 (and above) then it should be possible by adding counters in the code like:

```
Type perfModuleType = typeof(PerformanceCollectorModule);

PerformanceCollectorModule perfModule = (PerformanceCollectorModule)server.ApplicationServices.GetServices<ITelemetryModule>()
.FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetType() == perfModuleType);

perfModule.Counters.Add(
      new PerformanceCounterCollectionRequest(
          @"\.NET CLR Memory(??APP_CLR_PROC??)\# GC Handles", "GC Handles"));
```

If it's compiled as a pure netcoreapp then currently it's not supported.